# How do I interpret the binary of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject) describes the PyArrayObject struct.

In a Python session, I have the following:

```
>>> t_ar1 = np.linspace(0, 15, 16).reshape((4, 4))
>>> print(hex_fmt(string_at(id(t_ar1), 80).hex()))
0100000000000000
40b06eecbd7f0000
3053b973bf550000
02000000ffffffff
70eaa873bf550000
80eaa873bf550000
50c826adbd7f0000
00b66eecbd7f0000
01050000322c2033
0000000000000000
```

From my understanding, the third line is a pointer to the actual data of the array. Viewing the data there, I find

```
>>> print(hex_fmt(string_at(id(0x55bf73b95330), 96).hex()))
0200000000000000
4049a801be7f0000
0200000000000000
3053b933fd560100
489601adbd7f0000
10ab27adbd7f0000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
d09501adbd7f0000
b0aa27adbd7f0000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
```

Here, I'm expecting to see the floating point numbers 0.0 - 15.0 somewhere. However, I can't seem to find them. What's going on here?

Comment: What are `hex_fmt` and `string_at`?

Comment: `string_at` is from the ctypes module. `hex_fmt` just pretty-prints the hex (it's unimportant).

Answer (score 1):

`string_at` is from `ctypes` module.

To get the data directly from a numpy array you need to interpret byte-string (obtained by means of `string_at`) as array of floating point numbers (8-byte doubles). So, we need to use struct module to interpret byte-string as array of numbers:

```
from ctypes import string_at
import numpy as np
import struct # needed to unpack data

t_ar1 = np.linspace(0, 15, 16).reshape((4, 4))
struct.unpack('16d', string_at(t_ar1.__array_interface__['data'][0], size=8 * 16))
```

> (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,
>   13.0, 14.0, 15.0)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
string_at(0x55bf73b95330, 96)
```

Rather than what I had,

```
string_at(id(0x55bf73b95330), 96)
```

In this case, you'll get

```
>>> print(hex_fmt(string_at(0x55bf73b95330, 96).hex()))
0000000000000000
000000000000f03f
0000000000000040
0000000000000840
0000000000001040
0000000000001440
0000000000001840
0000000000001c40
0000000000002040
0000000000002240
0000000000002440
0000000000002640
```

As expected.